# How to truncate the length of a result in AngularJS uib-typeahead

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-typeahead

I'm using the [Angular UI Bootstrap typeahead](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) as follows:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selectedUser"
    uib-typeahead="user as user.Name for user in allUsers | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8"/>
```

I'm looking to truncate the values of long results so that the dropdown doesn't overflow. In other text controls I can use `| trimValue:20`, but that doesn't seem to be implemented in the typeahead.

Comment: `trimValue` truncates the string to the given number of characters.

Comment: I understood that after you added that answer :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What **works**:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selectedUser"
    uib-typeahead="user as user.Name | trimValue:20 for user in allUsers | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8"/>
```

What **doesn't work**:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selectedUser"
    uib-typeahead="user as user.Name for user in allUsers | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8 | trimValue:20"/>
```

Comment: For future reference, I realized that the trimValue function I was using was actually a custom filter that someone else had written. It isn't a built-in Angular filter.